# Visual Basic, why Nothing?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In school, I worked primarily with Java, C, and Python. Now that I'm working, I am working with .Net all of the time. Occasionally I have to work on Visual Basic projects which has been an enjoyable learning experience but I seem to get hung up on a few things from time to time. One of my main problems comes from the fact that Visual Basic uses `Nothing` instead of `null` as in C# and F#.

`Nothing` and `null`, to me, seem to be basically the same with the exception that a non-nullable value type can be set to `Nothing` in Visual Basic and the value will be set to its default value (i.e. 0 for an Integer). In C#, if a non-nullable value type is set to `null` there will be a compile-time error. Having the default value of data types be  but making created types `Nullable` and setting values to `DBNull.Value` for working with databases throws me off. It's not intuitive switching to `Nothing` from `null`. I looked at the IL code of setting a string to null/Nothing in both C# and VB and each time it set the string to ldnull. So is there any underlying reason as to why Visual Basic uses `Nothing` instead of `null` as other .Net languages do?

tl;dr Why does Visual Basic use `Nothing` instead of `null`?

Comment: "Because the designers said so", "Because it's a different language", or something similar.

Comment: cause it does. It has been written that way. I don't think there is a constructive answer to this question.

Comment: I don't know the historical reason for choosing the keyword `Nothing`, but VB is a different language from than C# or F#. There are lots of differences. This is almost like asking, "why does VB use `Nothing` and Ruby uses `nil`?" or "why does English use 'Hello' and Spanish uses 'Hola'?"

Comment: I don't know this for sure but maybe its because `nothing` to someone without a background in programming is more intuitive than the word `null`.  To me it makes no sense.

Comment: Why does objective-c use Yes/No instead of True/False?

Comment: I knew coming in that different languages have different conventions and that the designers chose to design it as it is. I thought that this language difference was exceptional due to the closeness of VB and C# and there had to be a definitive reason. I guess this "question" was naive.

Comment: I think this was a reasonable question but perhaps could have been better worded. I think people assumed you were asking why the *keywords* were different ("null" vs "Nothing") which would be a poor question. You also asked why the semantics is different with assigning Nullithing to value types. I think that's a better question, although it might still get closed to be honest with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that VB is based on the original Basic, which is intende to be truly *BASIC*, easily understood by someone who is not a programmer.

If you try to explain to a non-programmer that what a value is, which makes more sense.

"The value of X is Nothing"

or

"The value of X is null"  --> Leads to "Huh"? What the heck is NULL??

Comment: Maybe true, but I suspect that there's a technical or historical motivation. Having three different ways to say the same thing (Null, Nothing, Empty) is not the right way to keep things simple.  It leads to abominations such as `String.IsNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How is that an abomination? Null and Empty are totally different states for a String, and having that method is just for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replicate the functionality of `nothing` in C# try using `default(int)` where `int` is the type of variable.

This is normally used with generics when the type is not known.

Answer (score 0):

`Nothing` is the keyword that was used in VB6 and earlier versions of VB.  I don't no why they chose that term, but they kept it in .NET because it is part of the core VB language syntax and for backwards compatibility.  Perhaps the originally chose it because it was a simpler term for novices to understand?